# Print XML Node Name + XPATH

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible in SQL SERVER to Query the XML in such a way that if the input XML was the one below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <genRetrieve xmlns:v1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
            <checkRetrieve>
                <party>
                    <user>
                        <first>BLA</first>
                        <last>last</last>
                    </user>
                    <media /> --This element will also need to be picked in output
                </party>
            </checkRetrieve>
        </genRetrieve>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Produce a table that has the text nodes/elements and their corresponding XPATH in a table?

```
TEXT NODE       XPATH
---------       ---------
first           /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/genRetrieve/checkRetrieve/party/user/first   
last            /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/genRetrieve/checkRetrieve/party/user/last
media           /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/genRetrieve/checkRetrieve/party/media
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution via `openxml`.

```
declare @idoc int, @doc varchar(max);
set @doc =
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <genRetrieve xmlns:v1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
            <checkRetrieve>
                <party>
                    <user>
                        <first>BLA</first>
                        <last>last</last>
                    </user>
                    <media>none</media>
                </party>
            </checkRetrieve>
        </genRetrieve>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @doc;

;with map as (
    select *
    from openxml (@idoc, '//*')
), rcte as (
    select localname, parentid, '/' + isnull (prefix + ':', '') + localname as XPATH
    from openxml (@idoc, '//*[text()]')
    where nodetype = 1 and [text] is not null -- localname <> '#text'
    union all
    select r.localname, m.parentid, '/' + isnull (prefix + ':', '') + m.localname + XPATH
    from rcte r
    inner join map m on r.parentid = m.id
)

select localname as [TEXT NODE], XPATH
from rcte
where parentid is null;

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

**UPD.** Solution with nodes numeration.

```
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @doc;

;with map as (
    select id, parentid, nodetype, localname, prefix, row_number() over(partition by parentid, prefix, localname order by id) as num
    from openxml (@idoc, '//*')
    where nodetype = 1 or (nodetype = 3 and [text] is not null)
), rcte as (
    select p.localname, p.parentid, '/' + isnull (p.prefix + ':', '') + p.localname + '[' + cast (p.num as varchar(50)) + ']' as XPATH
    from map c
    inner join map p on c.parentid = p.id
    where c.nodetype = 3
    union all
    select r.localname, m.parentid, '/' + isnull (prefix + ':', '') + m.localname + '[' + cast (m.num as varchar(50)) + ']' + XPATH
    from rcte r
    inner join map m on r.parentid = m.id
)

select localname as [TEXT NODE], XPATH
from rcte
where parentid is null;

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

**UPD 2.** Yet another solution showing VALUE and nodes without text.

```
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @doc;

;with map as (
    select id, parentid, nodetype, localname, prefix, [text]
        , row_number() over(partition by parentid, prefix, localname order by id) as num
    from openxml (@idoc, '//*')
    where nodetype = 1 or (nodetype = 3 and [text] is not null)
)
, rcte as (
    select  localname, parentid, '/' + isnull (prefix + ':', '') + localname + '[' + cast (num as varchar(50)) + ']' as XPATH, VALUE
    from (
        select p.localname, p.parentid, p.prefix, p.num
            , min (c.nodetype) as min_nodetype
            , min (case when c.nodetype = 3 then cast (c.[text] as nvarchar(max)) end) as VALUE
        from map p
        left join map c on p.id = c.parentid
        where p.nodetype = 1
        group by p.localname, p.parentid, p.prefix, p.num
    ) t
    where min_nodetype = 3 or min_nodetype is null
    union all
    select r.localname, m.parentid, '/' + isnull (prefix + ':', '') + m.localname + '[' + cast (m.num as varchar(50)) + ']' + XPATH, VALUE
    from rcte r
    inner join map m on r.parentid = m.id
)

select localname as [TEXT NODE], XPATH, VALUE
from rcte
where parentid is null;

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the provided answer. Would it be possible to distinguish the duplicated parent-child nodes with [n]? For example if  this was the xml:

  <user>
   <first>BLA</first>
   <last>last</last>
  </user> 
  <user>
   <first>BLA</first>
   <last>last</last>
  </user> 
  
the xpaths should be: 
  /Envelope/Body[1]/genRetrieve[1]/checkRetrieve[1]/party[1]/user[1]/first[1]
  /Envelope/Body[1]/genRetrieve[1]/checkRetrieve[1]/party[1]/user[1]/last[1]
  /Envelope/Body[1]/genRetrieve[1]/checkRetrieve[1]/party[1]/user[2]/first[1]
  ....

Comment: I've marked your solution as answer - Thank you. I did notice though that if the element doesn't have a value it is left out in the output, for example if <media>none</media> was instead <media /> it is not included in the output where in fact it should be. Would you be able to suggest a remedy? Also On the same table is it possible to show the VALUE of that element if it had any?

Comment: Solution becomes more and more complex =) See UPD 2.

Comment: the function is performing incredibly slow with a xml payload that has 30,000 elements and 8000 text nodes - i had to kill it after 15 minutes :( Please help